# How to get macros take again same line's from the file, when he came to the end of file

Tags: loops, imacros

How to get macros take again same line's from the txt file, when he came to the end of file. I have script that takes google+ url pages from file which have 35 links, then i have another one file with website links that i need to post on wall. Each web-link need to be posted on each of 35 google+ pages. At the moment script visit's all url's post first link from file as i need, but when he came's to the end of file, macros stops to work. Any sugestion's how can i make it?

Here is my script

```
var macros;
var loop = 1;
macros = "CODE:";
macros += "SET !DATASOURCE google_pages.txt" + "\n";
macros += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n";
macros += "URL GOTO={{!COL1}}" + "\n";
macros += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:\"kqa es\"" + "\n";
macros += "SET !DATASOURCE links.txt" + "\n";
macros += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}" + "\n";
macros += 'EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="div[class=\\"df b-K b-K-Xb URaP8 editable\\"]" CHARS={{!COL1}}' + "\n";
macros += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:\"d-k-l b-c b-c-Ba qy jt\"" + "\n";
loop += prompt("How many times to play macros?:", loop);

for(i = 1; i <= loop; i++) {
    iimSet("i",i)
    iimDisplay("Loop Plays: "+i)
    iimPlay(macros)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood this issue, you should view the following snippet:

```
var linesInTxt = 35;
var numToRepeat = 2;
var loop = numToRepeat*linesInTxt;
for (i = 1; i <= loop; i++) {
    var j = (i % linesInTxt == 0) ? linesInTxt : i % linesInTxt;
    iimSet("i", j);
    // further code here
}
```